# Get the size of a UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Is there a way to get the height / width from a `UIAlertAction`?

It does not appear to be a subclass of `UIView`, so is there a constant that is set for it in the `UIAlertController`?

Comment: What do you really want to do? `UIAlertController` cannot be customized.

Comment: I would like to determine its height to calculate the size of other objects in the view. Any ideas on how to get this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can get height / width of UIAlertController by

```
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
    alertController.view.frame.height
}
```

Note: Need to put some delay after present UIAlertController
[You will get alert part frame only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jxrr.png)

Comment: Does this return just the alert part of the entire view (including the dimmed part under the alert)?